# How to deal with different orders of integration between explained and explaining variables?

Tags: multiple-regression, forecasting, feature-selection, stationarity, unit-root

Is there a standard, or at least a valid, regression approach if you are trying to regress a dependent variable with a unit root against a set of stationary independent variables? I know I could difference both sides, but I have little reason to think the rationales that led me to this set explanatory variables would apply to to the differenced variables.

Comment: Could you provide an example?  I imagine there might be several ways of handling this, but they'd be application-specific.